# React display array of object to table in row span

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array of object, i need to show them in a table, where one row is divided into number of costs available. For example, in this one row is divided into two.

I am stuck at how to display adjustedAmount, paidAmount and cost type ?

Here is the obj i have :

```
const datdfa = [
{
  index: 500,
  schudule_number: "11010",
  scheduleAvailableBudget: 1598000,
  budgetedqty: 2000,
  paidQty: 3,
  availableBalance: 1595633,
  adjustedAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 3, "Material Cost": 0 }],
  paidAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 1059, "Material Cost": 1059 }]
},
{
  index: 2016,
  schudule_number: "11020",
  scheduleAvailableBudget: 21600,
  budgetedqty: 12,
  paidQty: 10,
  availableBalance: 3663,
  adjustedAmount: [{}],
  paidAmount: [{ "Labour Cost": 468, "Material Cost": 468 }]
}
];
```

And here is the table to display

```
{datdfa?.map((s, d) => {
    let uniqueWSID = `row_${d}`;
      return (
          ...
          <td valign="middle">
              {
                  (s.adjustedAmount)?.map((ad) => {
                      return(
                          <td>{ad.key}</td> // this does not shows up
                      );
                  })
              }
          </td>
```

and i have created a sandbox link - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-fire-hgmr3?file=/src/App.js:108-707)

What am i making wrong / how to display it in the table ?

Comment: sorry, updated to javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is simple here, just replace inner `td` with `text`, like this:

```
      <td valign="middle">
          {
              (s.adjustedAmount)?.map((ad) => {
                  return(
                      <text>{ad.key}</text> // this should show up unless s.adjustedAmount doesn't exist or an empty array
                  );
              })
          }
      </td>
```

This may help you, I hope.

Comment: but it shows in one td, i have td which is split into two rows

Comment: then use `rowspan` for splitting row wise

Comment: @Learning visit this [example link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-rowspan-attribute/#:~:text=The%20rowspan%20attribute%20in%20HTML,than%20one%20cell%20or%20row.)